# undefined local variable or method verify_recaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I am following the [this](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) to implement captcha, but I am stuck at last step. Here is my controller:

```
 bug_report = BugReport.new(bug_report_params)
      if verify_recaptcha
        if bug_report.valid?
          bug_report.save!
          #render success
        else
          #throw error
        end
      else
         #Invalid captcha
      end
```

I am getting error saying: `undefined local variable or method verify_recaptcha`

Other codes are here:

## view

```
 <%= form_for :bug_report, url: bug_reports_path do |f| %>
        <%= recaptcha_tags %>
        <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
    <% end %>
```

## gemfile

```
gem "recaptcha", :require => "recaptcha/rails"
```

## recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = 'publik_key_here'
  config.private_key = 'private_key_here'
end
```

I am getting the following data in params:

```
{
utf8: "✓",
g-recaptcha-response: "Long text here",
commit: "Submit",
controller: "api/v1/bug_reports",
action: "index"
}
```

Please guide me, how to fix it.

Comment: Is your controller inheriting from `ActionController::Base` and did you restart your rails server after adding the gem?

Comment: No, my controller extends ApiController which extends ApplicationController and Yes I have restarted the server.

Comment: And your application controller inherits from?

Comment: ActionController::API basically I had created my project API only and here I have added the view for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, It looks like you have the rails app with `config.api_only = true` set in `application.rb`. For a list of what it actually does, check [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html) documentation.

One consequence of this is `ApplicationController` would inherit from `ActionController::API` instead of `ActionController::Base`. But if you look at recaptcha's [source code](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha/rails.rb#L7), the include is on `ActionController::Base`.

So, you can directly include `Recaptcha::Verify` module in your `ApplicationController`.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Recaptcha::Verify
...
end
```

Comment: When I tried this include Recaptcha::Verify It shows an error TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Module) then I changed it to include Recaptcha now it showing NameError: uninitialized constant Recaptcha

Comment: It may be because I could not find any module named Recaptcha in whole project

Comment: Can you try including it again after removing `require: "recaptcha/rails"` from the Gemfile?

Comment: Then I have to remove recaptcha.rb form initializers otherwise  it will throw uninitialized constant Recaptcha (NameError). Should I remove that?

Comment: Is it throwing? I don't think it would.

Comment: Just have `gem "recaptcha"` in your Gemfile. Leave out the `require: "recaptcha/rails"` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115279/discussion-between-charizard-and-imran).